# Using addTarget(target:action:) without self

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

Is there any way to use `addTarget` on something other than self (which seems to be the most common use case)?

Comment: do you know what is self?

Comment: The answer to your question is "yes". If you want more of an answer, please update your question with more specific details about what you are trying to do and what issues you are having.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can use a target other than `self`.  The most common use is to call `addTarget` with `self` where `self` is a reference to the viewController that the adds the `UIControl` to its view hierarchy.  But you aren't required to use it that way.  The `target` is merely a reference to an object, so you can pass it a reference to any object you want.  The `action` is a `Selector` which needs to be defined as an instance method on the `class` of that object, and that method must be available to Objective-C (marked with `@objc` or `@IBAction`) and it must take either no parameters, just the `sender`, or the `sender` and the `event`.

You can also pass `nil` as the target, which tells iOS to search up the responder chain for the `action` method.

---

Here's a little standalone example:

```
import UIKit

class Foo {
    @objc func buttonClicked() {
        print("clicked")
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let foo = Foo()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 200, width: 100, height: 30))
        button.setTitle("Press me", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(foo, action: #selector(Foo.buttonClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(button)
    }
}
```

Comment: I beat you to it by about a minute, with an answer that's almost exactly the same! :)

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of the responder chain trick. (Voted) Although that wouldn't work with our answers because our helper objects are not in the responder chain. If I remember correctly, peer views in the responder chain (like other buttons) wouldn't either. Only parent objects that are also UIResponders. (I used to use nil targets for menu actions on MacOS. I'm not sure I've ever used a nil target on iOS though.)

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly set up some other object to receive control actions. Consider the following view controller:

First, define a class who's job is to respond to button tap actions:

```
@objc class ButtonTarget: NSObject {
    @IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: Any) {
        print("In \(#function)")
    }
}
```

Now define a view controller that creates a `ButtonTarget` object

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

    lazy var buttonTarget = ButtonTarget() //Give the ViewController a `ButtonTarget`

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Add a taret/action to the button that invokes the method `buttonAction(_:)`
        button.addTarget(
          buttonTarget, 
          action: #selector(ButtonTarget.buttonAction(_:)), 
          for: .touchUpInside)
    }
}
```